# ionic 3 - cannot install onesignal plugin for ios using latest xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, ionic3, onesignal

I cannot create add ios platform for onesignal plugin. With android build its fine.

I did this:

```
$ ionic cordova platform add ios
```

the following errors failed.

```
apple-ios version check failed ("/Users/megasap/Documents/project/railerdotcom/railercom_parent/platforms/ios/cordova/apple_ios_version"), continuing anyways.

Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined

Failed to restore plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: /Users/megasap/.rbenv/shims/pod: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory

--save flag or autosave detected

Saving ios@~4.5.4 into config.xml file ...
[ERROR] Exception:
```

Full execution and error here:
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a926c54eb515bef5eb2f7019e36aa40f

This used to work, i just update to latest xcode 9.2 to compile other things. Is it something wrong with using the latest xcode ?

Comment: looks like you need to update cocoapods.. can you add the output for `crodova requirements` command?

Comment: you are right. it was sudo gem install cocoapods that did the trick

Comment: glad to hear it:) added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is here:

> Error: /Users/megasap/.rbenv/shims/pod: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory

Just update/install cocoapods to latest version as your xcode is also updated.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 5):

install and update `cocoapods` fix the problem

`sudo gem install cocoapods 
pod setup`

You may need to `rm` and `add` ios platform to make it work

Comment: I had to add the "pod setup" for it to proceed with the install, although I still received failing version checks.

Comment: The `pod setup` fixed it for me.